# Storing Optional returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like more clarification for optionals in Swift 1.2 e.g the snippet below

```
var numbers : [Array<String?>?]? = []
var getContact: String?

self.getContact = numbers![indexPath.row]?.first!

println(numbers![indexPath.row]?.first!)
println(getContact)

Optional("1-646-961-1869")
nil
```

Comment: try to post self contained code on SO. This means, code we can copy and paste and works the same for us as it does for you.

Comment: Do you really need an optional array whose elements are optional arrays of optional strings?

Comment: Yes I'm using this library https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook

Comment: There is, really, no reason to use anything less than the latest Swift.  (Really, if you find some ancient library that only uses "old Swift" - realistically just forget about it, there's "no library" if it does not even work with current Swift.)

Answer (score 1):

It might help to read `SomeType?` as “something that might either be a value of type `SomeType`, or `nil`.

Based on this, you could read this:

```
var numbers : [Array<String?>?]? = []
```

as:

> `numbers` is variable that might contain an array, or `nil`. In this part of the code it *does* contain an array, because you’ve assigned `[]` (an empty array) to it. The array contains values that are either arrays, or `nil`. And each element of those arrays is either a `String`, or `nil`.

What `nil` means depends on the context. It might indicate failure, or “not set yet”, or something else. For example, in `let maybeInt = Int("foo")`, `maybeInt` will be an `Int?` (which is shorthand for `Optional<Int>`), and will be set to `nil`, and in this case the `nil` means that `"foo"` cannot be turned into a number. In some other languages, you might instead get an exception, or the number 0 or -1, or a second parameter might be used to indicate failure, but Swift uses optionals.

Optionals can be overused. For example, an optional array is often suspicious – usually an empty array is sufficient. If you choose to make an array optional, ask the question “what is different between the array being `nil` and the array being empty?”. If there’s no difference, it probably shouldn’t be an optional, just a regular array.

(if the library/framework you’re using likes to traffic in these things without a clear reason, it might be a sign it’s not a very good library)

When you have an optional like `numbers` here, `!` means “I know this is an optional, but I don’t want to deal with the optionality so just assume it’s not `nil` and if it is, crash.”  Crash hard, right there, right then.

So for example, the array property `first` returns the first element of the array, unless the array is empty (like it is in your example code), in which case it will return `nil`. So in your example, writing `numbers![something]` won’t crash because of the `!`, because you set numbers to be some value. But `numbers!.first!` might crash if the array at index `something` is empty.

Lots of `!` in your code usually another bad sign, often suggesting that you (or the author of your library) shouldn’t have made something optional because it isn’t ever `nil`, or that there are failure cases (like that sometimes an array can be empty) that you’re ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer for a number of reasons. First, this kind of use of optionals is generally frowned upon because it's error-prone and hard to understand. Second, there isn't much context for us to work with. Third, most people are using Swift 2.0 at this point because it's backwards-compatible.

If you're trying to understand how optionals work, you might find [my tutorial on Swift optionals](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/12/optionals) useful.